# Rails not including attribute in SQL Query even though specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Despite providing the name, the SQL query clearly shows that it's not being passed properly. Rails console doesn't require any whitelist parameters as far as I'm aware, but I've included my controller as well.

Query in rails console: `Profession.first.skills.create(name: 'rails')`

```
  Profession Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "professions".* FROM "professions" ORDER BY "professions"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Skill Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "skills" WHERE "skills"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "twitter"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "skills" ("profession_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["profession_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-12-18 12:22:11.154775"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-18 12:22:11.154775"]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Not sure what's going on here.

Validation errors are still working though...

Valid object:

```
 :027 > Skill.new(name: "rails", profession: Profession.first).valid?
  Profession Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "professions".* FROM "professions" ORDER BY "professions"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Skill Exists (1.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "skills" WHERE "skills"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "twitter"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => true
```

Name being detected for validations:

```
 :020 > Skill.create!(name: String.new, profession: Profession.first)
  Profession Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "professions".* FROM "professions" ORDER BY "professions"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Skill Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "skills" WHERE "skills"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", ""], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank
    from (irb):20
```

Max Length:

```
:023 > Skill.create!(name: "sjadfkahskdfkjsahdfkjaskjdfkjhsdjkfhksajhfjksahasdljflasjdlfkjaskldjflkasjdklfjklasjdklfjlasjdflkjasklfjsdfhkjsahkjdfhjkasdhfkjhkj", profession: Profession.first)
  Profession Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "professions".* FROM "professions" ORDER BY "professions"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Skill Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "skills" WHERE "skills"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "sjadfkahskdfkjsahdfkjaskjdfkjhsdjkfhksajhfjksahasdljflasjdlfkjaskldjflkasjdklfjklasjdklfjlasjdflkjasklfjsdfhkjsahkjdfhjkasdhfkjhkj"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name is too long (maximum is 50 characters)
    from (irb):23
```

**ProfessionsController**

```
class ProfessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @profession = Profession.new
  end

  def create
    @profession = Profession.find_by(name: profession_params[:name])
    skill_params = get_nested_params(profession_params, :skills_attributes)

    if @profession
      # Save skill under existing profession
      @skill = Skill.create(name: skill_params[:name], profession_id: @profession.id)
    else
      @profession = Profession.new(name: profession_params[:name])
      if @profession.save {
        saved_profession = Profession.find_by(name: profession_params[:name])
        saved_profession.skills.create(name: "twitter")
        # Skill.create(name: skill_params[:name], profession_id: Profession.find_by(name: profession_params[:name])).save!
      }
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profession.save || @skill.save
        format.js { render layout: false }
        format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, notice: 'Profession was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, notice: 'Skill was not created.' }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def profession_params
    params.require(:profession).permit(:name,
                                       skills_attributes: [:id,
                                                           :name,
                                                           :starting_date,
                                                           :profession_id,
                                                           :_destroy])
  end

  def get_nested_params parent_params, nested_params
    nested_attrs = parent_params[nested_params]
    nested_attrs[nested_attrs.keys[0]]
  end
end
```

**Updated:**
Error from controller when using `saved_profession.skills.create(name: "twitter")`

```
Started POST "/professions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-19 01:50:50 +1300
Processing by ProfessionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "profession"=>{"name"=>"software", "skills_attributes"=>{"1513601431887"=>{"name"=>"rails", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Profession"}
  Profession Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "professions".* FROM "professions" WHERE "professions"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "software"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Profession Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "professions" WHERE "professions"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "software"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "professions" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "software"], ["created_at", "2017-12-18 12:50:50.202270"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-18 12:50:50.202270"]]
  Profession Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "professions".* FROM "professions" WHERE "professions"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "software"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Skill Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "skills" WHERE "skills"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "twitter"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "skills" ("profession_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["profession_id", 4], ["created_at", "2017-12-18 12:50:50.205484"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-18 12:50:50.205484"]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)



ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (11, null, 2017-12-14, 4, 2017-12-18 12:50:50.205484, 2017-12-18 12:50:50.205484, null).
: INSERT INTO "skills" ("profession_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"):

app/controllers/professions_controller.rb:21:in `block in create'
app/controllers/professions_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

Comment: try to ! here => saved_profession.skills.create(name: "twitter"). (change this to saved_profession.skills.create!(name: "twitter") ) and show your log.

Comment: yeap just added the log under the updated section

Comment: Not sure what the actual cause was, but I reset my entire db and it worked. All associations are performing well. Tried resetting before but no luck, all goods now though. Very strange since all migration and model files remained the same post-reset.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `get_nested_params` as:

```
def get_nested_params(parent_params, nested_params)
  parent_params             # For logging purpose only
  # => {"name"=>"software", "skills_attributes"=>{"1513601431887"=>{"name"=>"rails", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}

  nested_params             # For logging purpose only
  # => :skills_attributes

  nested_attrs = parent_params[nested_params]
  # => {"1513601431887"=>{"name"=>"rails", "_destroy"=>"false"}}

  nested_attrs.values[0]    # Return this
  # => {"name"=>"rails", "_destroy"=>"false"}
end
```